# Alter highchart output to display start - end date

Tags: php, javascript, highcharts

I currently have the following highchart which display a start date and outputs the values for the next 31 days of data. Does anyone know how I may improve on this to include and end date so that I can filter the data by smaller specific amounts? On the x-axis I am also trying to only display labels that have data attached to them and hide any others. Any help is appreciated.

My code is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'line',
                marginRight: 130,
                marginBottom: 25
            },
            title: {
                text: '<?php echo $type ?>',
                x: -20 //center
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: [ <? php
                $start = $_POST["dateStart"];

                $dates = array();

                for ($i = 0, $days = date('t', strtotime($start)); $i < $days; ++$i) {
                    $dates[] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($start.' + '.$i.' day'));
                }
                echo "'".implode("', '", $dates)."'"; ?> ]
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Total Amount'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' + this.x + ': ' + this.y;
                }
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                x: -10,
                y: 100,
                borderWidth: 0
            },
            series: [ <? php
            foreach($array as $legend = > $data) {
                echo '{';
                echo "name: '".$legend."',";
                $values = array();
                for ($i = 0; $i < $days; ++$i) {
                    $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($start.' + '.$i.' day'));
                    $values[] = isset($data[$date]) ? $data[$date] : 0;
                }
                echo 'data: ['.implode(', ', $values).'],';

                echo '},';
            } ?> ]
        });
    });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the following IS NOT secure.  You should ALWAYS run a sanity check on data submitted by the user.

```
   xAxis: {
        categories: [ <? php
        $start = $_POST["dateStart"];
        $end = $_POST["dateEnd"];

        $dates = array();
        $current=$start;

        while($current<=$end){
            $dates[]=$current;
            $current=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($current.' + 1 day'));
        }

        echo "'".implode("', '", $dates)."'"; ?> ]
    },
```